# probability question with marbles

Tags: probability

I have $13$ different color marbles. One color is $5$ times likely to be chosen and another color is half as likely to be chosen. What is the probability that,

$1$. you choose the marble that is 5 times likely?

$2$. you choose the marble that is half as likely?

$3$. you choose any other marble that is not 5 times likely or half as likely?

The way I did this was weight the marbles. Suppose every marble weighed one. Then one of those thirteen would weigh $5$, while another would weight $0.5$. I then proceeded to multiply everything by $2$ to get rid of the fractions. So I would get,

$5$ times likely weighted $10$

half as likely weighted $1$

everything else weighted $2$.

Since there are $11$ marbles that are weighted $2$, it could be thought of as there being $22$ marbles total. So does that mean there is a $\displaystyle\frac{22}{33}$ chance of picking a marble that is neither $5$ times likely or half as likely or would it be $\displaystyle\frac{2}{33}$? Assuming my work is right, I don't understand how to tell which one it should be.

Answer (score 1):

All your reasoning for probabilities looks good.

The question (3) is somewhat ambiguous, so it could be either $\frac {2}{33}$ or $\frac {22}{33}$, depending on whether the probability sought is for each of the other marbles, or for any of them.

I would tend to go with the "any of the others" interpretation,  $\frac {22}{33}$.